# Not able to read or write in my HDD

Tags: system-installation

I've installed element OS on my SSD(120GB) and now I'm not able store data in hard drive(1TB)

If tried to mount was getting this error.

`` Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/kamalnrf/LENOVO: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda2" "/media/kamalnrf/LENOVO"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option. ``

Comment: Have you tried what it suggests? Start windows and shut it down again properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to fix the drive. Try this:

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY`

Where "X" is the drive and "Y" is the partition (on an NTFS partition). It should work some magical incantation in the background for you and when it's done you should have a mountable NTFS drive.

So in your case, try this:

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2`

Please let me know if that helps any.